# How to implement paypal in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I have developed an site using Codeigniter and I want to put paypal for one of my application.For that I have followed many forms like [**THIS**](http://skar-web.com/2012/10/27/codeigniter-paypal-library/) but while I followed all the steps,it giving me blank screens...Can anyone tell me or even suggest me for the better tutorial for Paypal..Thanks in advance..

Comment: what error you are getting? Are you redirect to paypal website or not?I have seen that link and i found that live mode is false `$config['paypal_live'] = FALSE` so your paypal_url must be `var $paypal_url =https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`

Comment: Its giving me Server Error @RajJagani.and it is not wrking even I changed as you said

Comment: are you testing it on `localhost` or `remote server`? because if you testing it on `localhost` than i guess it might not work another way is you can `debug using this funtion @mail('Your mail_id','subject_nam','Your variable name')` put this function just before when you get the error. but this  works only on `remote server not localhost`

Comment: Iam testing at local server only..

Comment: I have also done paypal integration and it not work on `localhost` for me but when i try on remote server it works..so please try on `server`

Answer (score 1):

```
use following paypal form pattern for paypal payment

//$urlpaypal = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
//$urlpaypal = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";//sandbox

<form method="post" name="frmPayPal" id="frmPayPal" action="<?=$urlpaypal ?>">

<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?=$id?>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2"> 
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?=$businessId?>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_cmd" value="_cart"> 
<input type="hidden" name="handling_cart" value="<?=$shipprice?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_ext-enter" /> 
<input type='hidden' name='upload' value='1'> 
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1"> 
<input type="hidden" name="lc"  value="<?php echo $lccode;?>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="bn"  value="PP-SubscriptionsBF"> 
<input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="<?=base_url()?>img/logo.jpg"> 
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?=base_url()?>index.php/payment/receipt/<?php echo $id;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?=base_url()?>index.php/payment/notify"> 
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?=base_url()?>index.php/payment/cancle"> 
<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="<?=base64_encode($invoiceId)?>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo $currencycode;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="cs" value="0" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?=$customFieldValue?>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="discount_amount_cart" value="<?=$discount_amount?>"> 
<input type="hidden" name="cc_number" value="123"> 
<input type="hidden" name="cpp_ headerback_ color" value="78f3f5"> 
<input type="hidden" name="cpp_ headerborder_color" value="78f3f5"> 
<input type="hidden" name="cpp_payflow_ color" value="78f3f5">
</form>

and js code for auto form submission in one second
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
setTimeout("document.forms['frmPayPal'].submit()", 1000);
</script>
```